# SQL query help in where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am working on a report query which need to display orders contain both p type items and other non p items(non P items are of 50 items), they want order details that combine both type of items

Below is the query which I have prepared, but this query also displaying ptype orders which are not combined with non p items.

```
SELECT
  vwOrD.ONUMBER,
  vwOrD.ITEMID,
  vwITEMs.cat,
  vwITEMs.id
FROM vwITEMs
INNER JOIN vwOrD
  ON vwITEMs.ITEMID = vwOrD.ITEMID
INNER JOIN vwOrders
  ON vwOrD.ONUMBER = vwOrders.ONUMBER
WHERE vwOrders.CUSTID        = 'test'
  AND vwOrders.CREATEDATE >= '1-1-2016'
  AND vwOrders.CREATEDATE <= '11-28-2016'
  AND vwOrD.ONUMBER       IN
  (SELECT vwOrD.ONUMBER
   FROM vwOrD
   INNER JOIN vworders
    ON vwOrD.ONUMBER = vwOrders.ONUMBER
   INNER JOIN vwITEMs
    ON vwITEMs.ASCITEMID = vwOrD.ASCITEMID
    WHERE vwOrders.SOLDTOCUSTID  = 'test'
      AND vwITEMs.cat          = N'PI' -- Pitems cat= pi, id = c
      AND vwITEMs.id           = 'C'
      AND vwOrders.CREATEDATE >= '1-1-2016'
      AND vwOrders.CREATEDATE <= '11-28-2016' --group by          vwOrD.ONUMBER
      -- having count(1) > 1
  )
ORDER BY
  vwOrD.ONUMBER
```

sample output generated:

```
  ornumber  idnum  categ id  id
        12    xxx        pi   c 
        12    xxx     nonpi   c
        11    yyy        pi   c
        10    qqq        pi   c
```

results expected

```
12 xxx    pi c
12 xxx nonpi c
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. In order to help we need some more details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the columns in your sub-query are different, but I don't think that's the root of your trouble.

You are using your subquery to make sure that for each row you are returning, there is an item in that order with a `'pi'` item.  That's a little different from what you said you were trying to do.

The query below returns rows that are `'pi'` or `'nonpi'` that have another row for that `onumber` that is also `'pi'` or `'nonpi'` but is not the same `cat` as the row it is checking against.

```
select 
    d.onumber 
  , d.itemid
  , i.cat
  , i.id 
  from vwitems as i
    inner join vwOrD    as d on i.itemid = d.itemid 
    inner join vwOrders as o on d.onumber = o.onumber 
  where o.custid = 'test' 
    and o.createdate >= '1-1-2016' 
    and o.createdate <= '11-28-2016' 
    and exists (
      select 1 
        from vwOrD
          inner join vwitems on vwitems.ascitemid = vwOrD.ascitemid  /* ascitemid vs itemid ? */
          and vwitems.cat = 'Pi'
          and vwitems.id = 'C' 
          and vwOrD.onumber=o.onumber
          )
    and exists (
      select 1 
        from vwOrD
          inner join vwitems on vwitems.ascitemid = vwOrD.ascitemid  /* ascitemid vs itemid ? */
          and vwitems.cat != 'Pi'
          and vwitems.id = 'C' 
          and vwOrD.onumber=o.onumber
          )
  order by d.onumber;
```

Comment: Hi,I have issues with Non p item types which are more than 50 different categories (other than p type items are considered as different categories) , so I am not able to use in operator for that.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, and I have updated the query.

Comment: this should really be done in a single EXISTS statement not 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
   d.onumber 
  ,d.itemid
  ,i.cat
  ,i.id 
from
    vwitems as i
    inner join vwOrD d
    on i.itemid = d.itemid 
    inner join vwOrders o
    on d.onumber = o.onumber 
    AND o.custid = 'test' 
    and o.createdate >= '1-1-2016' 
    and o.createdate <= '11-28-2016' 
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT
             1
          FROM
             vmItems i2
             INNER JOIN vwOrd d2
             ON i2.itemid = d2.itemid
          WHERE
             o.onumber = d2.onumber
          HAVING
             COUNT(DISTINCT i.Cat) > 1
             AND COUNT(CASE WHEN i.Cat = 'Pi' THEN 1 END) > 0)
```

This should preform better than 2 separate EXISTS statements.

Also you have all of the table you need already joined so you could use windowed functions with conditional aggregation and do it as well.  Here is a Common Table Express [CTE] version but it can also be placed as a derived table as well. This might perform better yet:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    select 
      d.onumber 
     ,d.itemid
     ,i.cat
     ,i.id 
     ,COUNT(CASE WHEN i.Cat = 'Pi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY o.number) as PiCount
     ,COUNT(CASE WHEN i.Cat <> 'Pi' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY o.number) as NonPiCount
    from
       vwitems as i
       inner join vwOrD d
       on i.itemid = d.itemid 
       inner join vwOrders o
       on d.onumber = o.onumber 
       AND o.custid = 'test' 
       and o.createdate >= '1-1-2016' 
       and o.createdate <= '11-28-2016' 
)

SELECT *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    PiCount > 0
    AND NonPiCount > 0
```

I partly wanted to show you these answers due to a pet peeve.  **You should put constraints that are on the joins in the ON conditions NOT WHERE clause.**  When you are doing an `inner join` you wont notice anything different but as soon as you use an `OUTER JOIN` if you keep the conditions in the `WHERE` clause it would become an `inner join`.  Plus by limiting in the `ON` condition SQL can reduce the record set it deals with before having to join which could lead to better optimization yet.